# How to set custom input data in Model

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform

I'm using JTable for CRUD on my application. I've created method in model to save data in database

I need to add custom inputs "created" and "created_by" as shown in "$custom_data" variable and save it in database. Please note that, $form_data is getting saved successfully.

```
public function create() {
        $table = $this->getTable();
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post;
        $form_data = $jinput->get('jform', array(), 'array');
        $custom_data = array(
            'created'       => JFactory::getDate()->toSql(),
            'created_by'    => JFactory::getUser()->id
        );

        if (!$table->save($form_data)) {
            JError::raiseNotice(500, $table->getError());
            return FALSE;
        }

        return $form_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for another method, here it is :-)

The best place for such operations IMHO is the bind method of the JTable class. Below is an example how to override this method in your JTable class.

```
public function bind($src, $ignore = array())
{
    // Call parent's bind method
    if (parent::bind($src, $ignore))
    {
        // Do the following only when it's a new item ($this->id is 0 then)
        if (!$this->id)
        {
            $this->created = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();
            $this->created_by = JFactory::getUser()->id;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You don't need these lines anymore then:

```
$custom_data = array(
    'created' => JFactory::getDate()->toSql(),
    'created_by' => JFactory::getUser()->id
);
$data += $custom_data;
```

You are calling $table->save() in your model and this method will automatically call the bind() method for you.

Comment: Excellent Approach. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue with following:

just added $data = $form_data + $custom_data; Any other recommended method is appreciable.

```
public function create() {
        $table = $this->getTable();
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post;
        $data = $jinput->get('jform', array(), 'array');
        $custom_data = array(
            'created' => JFactory::getDate()->toSql(),
            'created_by' => JFactory::getUser()->id
        );
        $data += $custom_data;
        try {
            $table->save($data);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            if ($ex->getCode() == '404') {
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), 404);
            } else {
                JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('COM_HELPDESK_ERROR_OCCURRED'), 'error');
            }
        }

        $id = array(
            'id' => $table->id
        );

        $data += $id;

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: `JError` is deprecated. See here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/223/whats-the-correct-way-for-exception-handling

Comment: Good good :) Glad you solved it in the end. Don't forget to accept your answer when you're allowed to, so people can see it has been solved

Comment: I do it always :)